# Scrollwheel Event in X11

Tags: c, x11

I have looked all over, and was shocked to be unable to find anything on the topic.

I just want to be able to capture events from a simple mouse scrollwheel.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yep, this is incredibly confusing. That's because X11 decided to assign mouse scroll wheel events as mouse button 4 and 5. Receiving scrollwheel events is the same as receiving mouse button press events (ButtonPress events according to /usr/include/X11/X.h). Note also that the header file defines Button1..Button5. Buttons 4 and 5 correspond to up or down-- maybe not that order, you'll have to determine this empirically. The header file never mentions scrollwheel events.

Thankfully, higher level APIs (like GDK) explicitly provide scrollwheel support by name.

Comment: Also not that each 'tick' of the scrollwheel will generate both a Press and a Release event, right after each other. You can safely ignore the Release events for these buttons.

Comment: @MultimediaMike So I've _finally_ gotten a chance to work on this.  Part of my initial problem earlier was I wasn't capturing the correct events.  Two questions: is the amount scrolled specified (or is it just multiple events), and how is horizontal scrolling done?

Comment: @imallet To handle horizontal scrolling, you need to listen for buttons 6 and 7 that correspond to left and right.

Comment: @matteodelabre Alright. Extrapolating from the values of `Button(1|2|3|4|5)`, I guess (since they aren't defined) they have values `6` and `7`.